# Spark: out of memory exception caused by groupbykey operation

Tags: apache-spark

I have a large file where each line is a record with an id as key.

```
val lines = fileRdd.map(line => (line.id, line))
```

then I group lines by id

```
val groupedLines = lines.groupByKey()
```

so the lines with the same id will be shuffled to one worker node.
a tuple in RDD groupedLines is like
*id -> Iterable(line1, line2, ..., lineN)*
if lots of lines have the same id, then the size of the tuple's value *Iterable(...)* will be quite large, and if it is larger then the JVM memory limit of the process on the machine, out of memory problem may happen.

So whether this problem exists, and if yes does anyone know how to deal with this case, too large size of value of a tuple in grouped RDD?
Can we just use *sc.parallelize(t._2.toSeq)* to change the value of the tuple to be another nested RDD, something like
*RDD[(id,RDD)]*

Thanks :P

Comment: Try setting spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles configuration parameter to true and spark.storage.memoryFraction to 0. Also please list some metrics - size of file, amount of memory in cluster.

Comment: Can u specify file size your RAM size and sparkConf ? Using single node right ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to increase `spark.executor.memory` to a value larger than the one you are using currently. Recommended is `5g`.

Can you provide the stack trace of such error?

Answer (score 0):

def groupByKey(numPartitions: Int): RDD[(K, Seq[V])]

Try to increase parameter

```
numPartitions
```